# linux: username/password accepted with interactive ftp but 'login incorrect' with wget

Tags: ftp, wget

I'm trying to download some data from an ftp site but am having trouble with the log on. I know the username/password is correct because it works when I use ftp interactively. However when I try using wget I get:

```
Logging in as $username...
Login incorrect.
```

I've tried the following commands from the command line:

```
wget -r -nd -A "path/to/data/*/*hdf" --ftp-user=$username --ftp-password=$password ftp:$ftpSite

wget -r -nd -A "path/to/data/*/*hdf" --user=$username --password=$password ftp:$ftpSite

wget -r -nd -A "path/to/data/*/*hdf" --ftp-user=$username --ask-password ftp:$ftpSite

wget -r -nd -A "path/to/data/*/*hdf" --user=$username --ask-password ftp:$ftpSite
```

And I always get the same "Login incorrect" failure.

I am running from the command line without using variables. I am only using variables in this question to censor sensitive info.

I would use mget in ftp but it's my understanding that I can't use wildcards to grab files from multiple subdirectories. When I try "mget */*hdf" I get a "No such file or directory" error. However I know the data is there, because when I cd into one of the subdirectories and do "mget *hdf", it works

Answer (score 0):

User name and password settings specified in `.netrc` prevail over command line options `--user=*` of `wget`, so it ignores user name given in the command line.

Please check your `~/.netrc`.